# python - CURL Rest API data manipulation

Tags: python, rest, dataset

So I am using a curl statement to get a json string

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d 'plan=4' 'status=closed' https://example.com/rest/api/m_spl/search
```

It returns a long json string with columns then the content with the corresponding data underneath.

What's the best way to

- View the json string in columns or turn it into a csv?
- What is the best data structure to store the result so that I can sort, manipulate data? (array or list)?

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

- code
- websites with examples

thanks